# How to dynamically set contentScale in jetpack compose. Coil Image Loading

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've images which is stored in server or storage.

And I want to set contentScale to CROP if it is Landscape Image otherwise FIT

```
AsyncImage(
     modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(250.dp)
                    .clickable { onImageClick(it) },
     model = imageUrl,
     contentDescription = null,
     contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
)
```

so here `contentScale` is setted to `FIT` but I don't know how I can set it automatically according to the image orientation.

Isn't there any way to do something like this **Pseudocode** ->

```
 if(img.width > img.height){
   contentScale = ContentScale.CROP // since it is landscape 
 } else {
   contentScale = ContentScale.FIT
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using variables and then set them like this:

```
val intrinsicWidth = img.intrinsicSize.width
val intrinsicHeight = img.intrinsicSize.height
```

//then use it

```
contentScale = if (intrinsicWidth > intrinsicHeight) ContentScale.Crop else ContentScale.Fit
```

//then in your AsyncImage:

```
AsyngImage(modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(250.dp)
                .clickable { onImageClick(it) },
 model = imageUrl,
 contentDescription = null,
 contentScale = if (img.intrinsicSize.width > img.intrinsicSize.height) ContentScale.Crop else ContentScale.Fit)
```

Comment: But I can't get `intrinsicWidth` or `intrinsicHeight`  using `img` means how can I get I don't have image I've only `imageUrl`